# Process kill count with a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to kill a certain process in windows when the process count exceeds the value i have set.

```
set a=tasklist | find /I /C "example.exe"
set b=3
if a GTQ b ( 
TASKKILL /FI "USERNAME eq %USERNAME%" /IM example.exe /F /T)
```

The above is what I have been able to do until now but it doesn't seem to work
Thanks in advance all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "example.exe"') do set /a a=%%a
set /a b=3
if %a% GEQ %b% (
```

the `for /f` runs the command in 'single quotes' which requires the `|` redirector to be escaped. The result of the single-quoted command is assigned to `%%a` and thence to `a`

`set /a` is an arithmetic `set`

`%var%` evaluates to the *contents* of the nominated variable `var`

`geq` is the `greater than or equal to` operator.

Comment: When i apply the above solution, whatever i put in b it kills the proceses                                                                                                        for /f %%a in ('tasklist | find /I /C "example.exe"') do set /a a=%%a set /a b=9 if %a% GEQ %b% ( 
    TASKKILL /FI "USERNAME eq %USERNAME%" /IM example.exe /F /T
)                                                                                                                 Maybe i applied something wrong, i'm not very good with this :(